# About how big will this olive tree grow?

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, olive

[image]

It looks more like a bush now, but I'm wondering if it will grow into a tree?

Comment: Whereabouts in the world is it planted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It grows like a tree, relatively slow.  I don't agree with George's answer.  My olives tree are taller than 4m, and not so old. The younger one, I transported in a car around 7 years ago, and now it is taller than 5m.

But the worst part about olives are the roots. They grow fast and will eventually surface, so I think it needs to be planted with more distance to edges.

In any case, olives  are quite resilient, but cold can be a problem (from cold, every 10 years or so I see them very damaged, but within a year, they will recover fully), so you can prune heavily and even move them.

Comment: I don't think I've changed the meaning of what you said, was just trying to make the use of English clearer, but if I have changed any meanings, please change back again.

Comment: @Bamboo: Thank you for the editing. My English is bad, but I also tend to write quickly the answers.  I think you changed the meaning with the cold resistant. I wanted to stress that the olive trees are resistant in general (heavy pruning, moving them, but also  they don't suffer as many diseases as other planted tree. Cold is one exception of olive resistance: they suffer it, OTOH they tend to take care themselves.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense, because I know they're not good in cold weather - altered the answer again, is that better?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it will grow into a tree. Depending on conditions, this could take a very long time and they can live for well over a thousand years. The ultimate size will depend on the cultivar - wild trees will make between 8 and 15m but may take hundreds of years to get there. Most cultivars will remain substantially smaller. It is unlikely to reach much more than 4m in your lifetime, but will develop a woody trunk.